# Fix mouseover with toggle buttons and child DIV's

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, mouseover

I have a toggle script that works great, but I'm trying to add a mouseover effect and I'm having trouble with it.

I have four tags, two of which are simple DIV's with background colors, and I have two additional Buttons with background images.

I created a mouseover effect for all tags, but it doesn't look right when I click on a button. Once I click a button, the button needs to change background-position upon click and the mousever should stop over the buttons.

Here is my link:  http://jsfiddle.net/eriksnet/9cr4F/1/

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, just updated the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `#r6:hover .gnM` has a higher precedence over `.button-toogle-on`. CSS has an hierarchy of CSS, based on where it's defined, if it's inline or not, how many elements you specify. Read more [here](http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html).

Anyways, this works:

```
#r6 #bxGender .button-toggle-on {
    background-position: 0 -120px
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9cr4F/3/

Comment: Thank you.  Is it possible to turn off the mouseover altogether and change the DIV's to green and button background-position to "0 -180px" when a button has been clicked ???  Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Once I click either Male or Female, I would like the following: (1) two DIV's background color to change to #2F2F2F AND the mouseover effect stop AND (2) the button not selected background-position to "0 -180px"

Comment: Kinda hackish, but here ya go: http://jsfiddle.net/9cr4F/8/ EDIT: Changed the font color of 2 divs when there's a selection: http://jsfiddle.net/9cr4F/9/

Comment: Thank you Little Big Bot.  Your help went toward a new non-profit organization that will be launching in the US soon.  Very grateful for your help!! God bless.